# Why does ResNet double its feature channels after each stage rather than quadrupling?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, resnet

I'm curious about the reasoning behind the common pattern in vision backbones like ResNet and others, where the number of feature channels is **doubled** at the end of each stage.

One might say that quadrupling would be more natural since this would keep the feature "size" consistent between stages.

i.e. 256 channels at 32x32 resolution is 262,144 features, but
512 channels at 16x16 resolution is 131,072 features (half as many)

Couldn't this limit the number of high-level features that a detector could make use of? Have there been experiments that explore this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see a good reasoning as to why you want to keep the feature "size" "consistent" across the layers. If you look at the idea of Deep CNN, it's more about using the representation of the small image regions learned in initial layers to learn high level and more complex features in deeper layers.
So how would you argue that the feature vector of length "l" in a layer n doesn't encode the same amount of information as a feature vector of the same length in layer n-1.

I suppose these decisions are much more experimental than analytical.

You can look at this paper to build more intuition about what you are asking.

[https://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Efergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf)